# Why mapping nullable collection is always not null in dart?

Tags: flutter, dart, null, nullable, elvis-operator

```
1      factory SuggestSessionResult.fromJson(Map<String, dynamic> json) {
2        final String? error = json['error'];
3        final List<Map<String, dynamic>>? items = json['items'];
4        return SuggestSessionResult(
5          items
6            ?.map((it)=>SuggestItem.fromJson(it))
7            .toList(),
8          error
        );
      }
```

Hello!
As you can see, I've not used null-aware operator in line 7 and that's ok for compiler. Moreover, when I use it, the analyzer says the receiver can't be null.
Why so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In Dart 2.12, `?.` was made short-circuiting.

From the [Understanding null safety](https://dart.dev/null-safety/understanding-null-safety) document:

> To address this, we borrowed a smart idea from C#’s design of the same feature. When you use a null-aware operator in a method chain, if the receiver evaluates to `null`, then *the entire rest of the method chain is short-circuited and skipped*.

In your case, `.map()`, *if called*, cannot return `null` (because [`Iterable.map`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/dart-core/Iterable/map.html) does not return a nullable type).  Therefore `.toList()` either will never be called (because `.map()` was not called earlier in the method chain) or will be guaranteed to be called on a non-null value.